# Preference DataStore in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I just implemented preference data store in kotlin, and now I am trying to implement datastore preference in java with encryption and decryption store and retrieve of data. Looking for any reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [security-crypto](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data) of Android JetPack